# Open many txt files and sort into two dfs

Tags: python, pandas, loops, import

I need to open and process hundreds of .txt files based on their names and the folder names that they are contained within, into two data frames.

**The folder structure:**

I have a single folder, containing a number of sub-folders, each named with the date that the data was recorded, in this format:`YYY-MM-DD`, example: `2019-0-14`

**The file structure:**

In each of the above folders, there are 576 files. There are two sets of measurements (based on 2 locations), taken each 5 minutes over every 24 hour period (12*24*2 = 576). The files are named as below:

```
hhmmssILAC3octf.txt  for the indoor location
hhmmssOLAC3octf.txt  for the outdoor location
```

Where `hhmmss` is the hour, minute and second of each 5 minute file and `IL` is indoors and `OL` is outdoors.

**File contents:**

Every file contains 5 rows of data, one for every minute. This data is the same type of data and the same length of data, separated by comas.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I need to create two data frames: one for each location, with the date (folder name) and time (file name and position [line 1:5]) as a datetime index, based on the folder it is contained within, the name of the file and line number in the .txt

I also need to rename all the columns/variables once imported with the same names, but prefixed with an indoor or outdoor, based on if its location. Example: indoor_20hz.

I use Python and Pandas myself, but have never tried to solve a problem like this. Please can someone point me in the right direction...

Thank you.

Comment: You should consider using `glob.glob()` to locate the file names, extracting the time data from the file names, and then using `pandas` to process the data. If you are uninterested in working on this problem yourself there are a number of freelance programmers on the internet you could pay.

Comment: I use Python and pandas myself, but have never done anything like this. I dont know where to start and I am looking for some advice.

Comment: You should consider using `glob.glob("**", recursive=True)` to locate the file names, extracting the metadata from the file names using string slices, reading in the individual files with `pandas.read_csv()` and assembling them into a large dataframe. That is the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the following code:

```
import os
import fnmatch

start_dirctory='.'  # change this
df_result= None
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(start_dirctory):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.txt'):
                full_name=os.path.join(path, file)
                df_tmp= pd.read_csv(full_name)
                # add the line number
                df_tmp['line_number']= range(df_tmp.shape[0])
                # add the code here that generates the infos 
                # you additionally need here to the df
                # then concatenate the files together
                if df_result is None:
                    df_result= df_tmp
                else:
                    df_result= pd.concat([df_result, df_tmp], axis='index', ignore_index=True)
```

As a result, you should have the content of all files in `df_result`. But you need to make sure, that the files have the same column structure, otherwise you need to fix it above. You also need to add the additional infos you need in place of "# add the infos you need here to the df".

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. This works, but doesn't add the date and time as the index, how do I add this in? It also combines all files and doesn't separate indoor and outdoor, how do I sort these into two separate dfs?

Comment: If date and time is the only index, you need to do `df_tmp.add_index([date_column, time_column], inplace=True)`.

Comment: but there arent isnt a `date_column` or a `time_column` - how do i create these as part of the import process?

Comment: If the directory containing your file date, then you can do `df_tmp['date']=os.path.basename(path)`. The time you get by `file[:6]`.

Comment: Sorting indoor and outdoor is just something like `df_tmp[column_in_out]='IL'` and `concat` the result of this and of `df_tmp[column_in_out]='IL'` to different dataframes. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution, albeit im sure this isnt the most elegant way to get the final result:

```
import os
import fnmatch
import pandas as pd

start_dirctory='DIR'  # change this
df_result= None
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(start_dirctory):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.txt'):
                full_name=os.path.join(path, file)
                df_tmp= pd.read_csv(full_name, header=None)
                df_tmp['date']=os.path.basename(path)
                df_tmp['file']=os.path.basename(file)
                # df_tmp.set_index([df_tmp['date'], df_tmp['time']], inplace=True)
                # add the line number
                df_tmp['line_number']= range(df_tmp.shape[0])
                # add the code here that generates the infos 
                # you additionally need here to the df
                # then concatenate the files together
                if df_result is None:
                    df_result= df_tmp
                else:
                    df_result= pd.concat([df_result, df_tmp], axis='index', ignore_index=True)

# Slice filename from 6 to 7 to get location
df_result['location'] = df_result['file'].str.slice(6,7)

# Slice filename from 0 to 6 to get time
df_result['time'] = df_result['file'].str.slice(0,6)

# Combine date and time and format as datetime
df_result['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_result['date'] + ' ' + df_result['time'], errors='raise', dayfirst=False)

# Round all the datetimes to the nearest 5 min
df_result['date'] = df_result['date'].dt.round('5min')

# Add line number as minutes to the date
df_result['date'] = df_result['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df_result['line_number'],unit='m')

del df_result['file']
del df_result['line_number']
del df_result['time']

# Make the date the index in df
df_result = df_result.set_index(df_result['date'])

# Delete date in df
del df_result['date']

# Change columns and rename df_result
df_result.columns = ['10hz', '12.5hz', '16hz', '20hz','25hz','31.5hz','40hz','50hz','63hz','80hz','100hz','125hz','160hz','200hz','250hz','315hz','400hz','500hz','630hz','800hz','1000hz','1250hz','1600hz','2000hz','2500hz','3150hz','4000hz','5000hz','6300hz','8000hz','10000hz']
```